# Kohana 3.2 custom validation error messages for one model or a field

Tags: php, kohana

I have my general validation messages in `application/messages/validation.php` and I need a custom message when I'm validating the 'password' field for my User model. This is my initial code:

```
try
{
  ORM::factory('user', Auth::instance()->get_user())->update_user($values);
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
  $errors = Arr::merge($errors, $e->errors(TRUE));
  if (Arr::get($errors, '_external'))
  {
    $errors = Arr::merge($errors, Arr::get($errors, '_external'));
    unset($errors['_external']);
  }
}
```

And I tried: `$e->errors('')`, `$e->errors()`, copying `application/messages/validation.php` to `application/messages/user.php`, putting `'password' => array('regex' => 'message')` inside of those files, I tried mixing many possibilities of all this. I read the source code for the exception class, but I can't understand what's wrong. According to [this](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9775/custom-validation-error-messages-in-kohana-3./p1) post, it can be done, but didn't worked for me that way.
I appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in `ORM_Validation_Exception->generate_errors()`. What you are trying to do should be as simple as calling `$e->errors('validation')`, and messages would come from `application/validation/user.php` (it appends the ORM model alias).

I haven't reported it yet, but I think [this bug report](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4385) touches on it anyways. Hopefully it gets fixed.

In `modules/orm/classes/kohana/orm/validation/exception.php`, change line 153 to `$errors[$key] = $this->generate_errors(`**`$alias`**`, $object, $directory, $translate);`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If there's a validation function you could try this in APPPATH/messages/validation.php.

```
return array(
   'password' => 'your password text' // this way it will always be replaced
   'Model_User::password' => 'your custom password message' // And here just for the Model_User
);
```